# MongoDB ISODate and timezones on Node API

Tags: node.js, mongodb, date, datetime, strongloop

I built an API using Node, with the IBM Strongloop framework along with a MongoDB database.
I have a problem with date timezones.
On the frontend, I have a react datepicker that creates date objects.

I am in France, so *GMT+1*. If I create a **date of birth** for January 6th, 2000 on the frontend, the XHR request will send **"2000-01-05T23:00:00.000Z"** to the API.

If I try new Date('2000-01-05T23:00:00.000Z') on the frontend, I get the correct date **Thu Jan 06 2000 00:00:00 GMT+0100 (CET)**

On the API server, which is at timezone *GMT+0*, if I check the database I can see it as ISODate("2000-01-05T23:00:00Z")

If I try new Date('2000-01-05T23:00:00Z') on the server, I get the wrong date **Wed Jan 05 2000 23:00:00 GMT+0000 (UTC)**

Of course my users can have different timezones so setting the server timezone to GMT+1 won't solve the problem.

What is the correct solution ? Send dates to the server as strings, without timezone, and let it build them as dates before inserting ? Or is there another way ?

Comment: and to complicate the problem further, note that the UTC offset for France is not always +1, it can also be +2 (for half the year summer daylight saving time) . same (and worse) for other geographical timezones. Also, it could change depending on the years (political decisions).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For "date only" data that need to be stored, I think it is '*easier*' to *break* the dateTime into only years, month and day. You transmit this information to your server, and create a new UTC DateTime object based on the year, month and date, stored server-side. Or simply store the 3 fields separately.

To get back this information you can use the `getUTCxxx()` (xxx being day, month or year) Javascript methods.

Or you can create a new UTC dateTime with correct date front-side and send it the back-end, your pick.

If you do that, you will have the correct date stored in the backend (like if it was correct-date at midnight UTC) .

And then, when you query the value for display on the Front-end, you can force to take into account only the (UTC) date part of your datetime data, which are the correct year, month and day.

Also, for Javascript I strongly recommend to use some external "proper" frameworks to handle date and time, like [momentJS](https://momentjs.com/) if you can.

Answer (score 0):

Its ideal to save the data server side in a consistent manner (GMT) like you are doing now. It should be left upto the client application to send/display the correct offset date based on its time zone.

Comment: unfortunately, it doesn't work so well for 'date only' data, like the birth date example of OP.

Comment: Oh I see that now. In that case, I guess it would be a better option to force GMT end to end since relative moment of time is not relevant. The client app should be aware of this though.

Comment: Yes... And it's really a pain to handle with the (poor) Javascript DateTime native handling.